# Not able to add Emoji's as comment "OperationalError :Incorrect string value: '\\xF0\\x9F\\xA5\\xB0' for column 'content' at row 1"

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django

when I tried to add emoji's i'm getting this error did not workout even CharField getting the same error.
models.py[image: error pop's when i tried to add emojis]

```
class Comment(models.Model):
post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='comments', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
content = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=False)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

def __str__(self):
    return self.content

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.post.pk})  # returns a string to the post detail that uses the pk of the comment instance. post. pk to link to the correct detail page ie. /post/

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Comment, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
    n = 4
    truncatewords = Truncator(self.content).words(n)
    notify.send(self.author, recipient=self.post.author, verb='commented "' + truncatewords + '" on your post!', action_object=self.post, description='comment', target=self)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow emoji characters you need to set column collation to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` which will allow all characters and also in the MySQL connection as well you need to set `charset` to `utf8mb4`.